# How is this returning a blank value?

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

So this code is meant to serve as a simple search system to go to certain records in a recordset. I originally had it so they had to click the btnGoToID button in order to perform the search.  I decided to just make it a little more user friendly and make it so the search field listened for the Enter button and that would perform the search as well.

The issue that I am running into when the code gets to `strID = Trim(Nz(Me.txtSearch.Value, ""))` the value will randomly come back as an empty string even though visually I can see that there is a value in the textbox.

I haven't been able to narrow down any pattern for when this issue occurs.  At this point I don't really even know how to troubleshoot this problem, nor the words to search for that could yield any results in Google.  All I can say is that it SEEMS like changing between records will affect whether or not the search goes through.

This has always worked up until I put in the txtSearch_KeyPress sub procedure.

```
'============================================================================
' txtSearch_KeyPress
'============================================================================
Private Sub txtSearch_KeyPress(KeyAscii As Integer)
    'If user pressed enter
    If KeyAscii = 13 Then
        Call btnGoToID_Click
    End If
End Sub



'============================================================================
' btnGoToID_Click
'============================================================================
' <<Purpose>>
' Allow the user to search for a specific ID 
'============================================================================
Private Sub btnGoToID_Click()
On Error GoTo Err_Handler

    Dim rs As Recordset
    Dim strID As String

    Set rs = Me.RecordsetClone

    strID = Trim(Nz(Me.txtSearch.Value, ""))

    If (strID <> "") Then

        'Go to the ID
        rs.FindFirst "ID = '" & strID & "'"

        If rs.NoMatch Then
            MsgBox "ID does not exist"
        Else

            'If we have a match, set the record as the current record
            Me.Bookmark = rs.Bookmark
        End If
    Else
        MsgBox "Please enter a valid ID.", vbOKOnly, "Invalid ID"
    End If


Exit_Handler:
On Error Resume Next

    Me.txtSearch.Value = ""
    rs.Close
    Set rs = Nothing
    Exit Sub

Err_Handler:
    Call LogError(Err.Number, Err.Description, "txtSearch on " & Me.Name)
    Resume Exit_Handler
End Sub
```

After the conversation in the comments I have narrowed down this question to be a whole lot simpler.  This yields an "Invalid use of null" error message even after there are several characters in the text field.  Why would that happen, and what can I do to make it pick up the values in the textbox?

```
'============================================================================
' txtUnitNoToSearch_KeyPress
'============================================================================
Private Sub txtUnitNoToSearch_KeyPress(KeyAscii As Integer)
    MsgBox Me.txtUnitNoToSearch
End Sub
```

Comment: I am not sure what the error might be. But it seems to me you could handle all of this with an _AfterUpdate event of the textBox

Comment: Wouldn't an AfterUpdate event only fire once they have left the field, if at all (it's an unbound field).  Can you expand on what you mean?

Comment: True, but unless you have defined the field to be multi-line, I believe pressing `enter` will result in the same thing

Comment: I have it set to be multi-lined only for the purpose of allowing the enter key to be "Caught". Since leaving it to default will just cause it to tab away.  Are you thinking change it from multi line so that when enter is pressed it tabs away, then use the OnUpdate event to call the search?

Comment: Yes I believe it is much simpler this way :)

Comment: The concern with that is if a user starts to type or enter anything in that field and has to navigate away for any reason the search function would fire even though the user wouldn't want it to.

Comment: You are right. It depends on what you want. Personally I don't believe it to be bad user experience; you have a text field that filters, you type sth and then it filters. It seems reasonable enough. :) But as already said, it is up to what you want :)

Comment: I am a suuuuper anal programmer so if I can't make it work exactly to what I would consider "perfect" I will stew over it for days.  Though our conversation did send me down an interesting path of troubleshooting that shows the root cause of the issue.  I have updated my main question.

Comment: Why are you trying to catch `KeyAscii` codes? You need to make sure that the name of the control (text box) you are referencing is correct. This can be done by typing `Me.` and identifying if intellisense can locate the name of that control. I think something is amiss here, and I'm still not sure why your function accepts the KeyAscii as a parameter

Comment: This is a keypress event, it accepts the KeyAscii by default.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think your problem is related to the fact that a text box has 2 properties, `.Value` and `.Text`, which appear similar but behave differently.

While you have an edit in progress in the text box, the changing content is available via the `.Text` property.  However, the content of the `.Value` property  has not yet been updated to match.

After the text box's *After Update* event, `.Value` will contain the new content.  And if focus has moved away from the text box, its `.Text` property will no longer even be available.

Sorry, I couldn't think how to explain that better.  But I think the situation will be clearer with this *KeyPress* event procedure:

```vb
Private Sub txtUnitNoToSearch_KeyPress(KeyAscii As Integer)
    Debug.Print "Text: '" & Me.txtUnitNoToSearch.Text & "'"
    Debug.Print "Value: '" & Me.txtUnitNoToSearch.Value & "'"
End Sub
```

Watch the output from `Debug.Print` in the Immediate window as you make changes to the context of the text box.  (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>g</kbd> will open the Immediate window.)

One final point is that just `Me.txtUnitNoToSearch` gets you its default property which is `.Value`.  Keep that in mind as you work through the rest of your code.

Comment: I just tested it and found out that the AfterUpdate event had never fired. You beat me to it :)

Comment: Wow, that is definitely the cause of this.  The .Text gives me exactly what I want, however the .Value still continues to say the value is null.  Thanks Hans!