# How to get a simple textbox, on an Access form, to behave

Tags: ms-access, textbox, vba

I have an Access 2010 form that is supposed to act like a dialog, and not intended to display any record-set data. On it are the following:

- an unbound Source textbox, called `source_file_txt`, to hold the name of a spreadsheet filename,
- a Browse button, called `browse_btn`, to open a file-finder dialog, which works well,
- an Import button, called `import_btn`, to initiate an import function, to be written later.

I'm trying, but failing, to enable/disable the Import button according to presence/absence of text in the Source textbox.
Here's my VBA code:

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
    Debug.Print vbCrLf & "Form_Load() " & Now()
    enable_import
End Sub

Private Sub source_file_txt_Change()
    Debug.Print vbCrLf & "source_file_txt_Change() " & Now()
    enable_import
End Sub

Private Sub source_file_txt_Dirty(Cancel As Integer)
    Debug.Print vbCrLf & "source_file_txt_Dirty() " & Now()
    enable_import
End Sub

Private Sub browse_btn_Click()
    Debug.Print vbCrLf & "browse_btn_Click() " & Now()
    source_file_txt = browsed_file()
    enable_import
End Sub

Private Sub enable_import()
    Debug.Print vbCrLf & "enable_import() " & Now()
    Debug.Print "source_file_txt:           " & source_file_txt
    Debug.Print "source_file_txt.Value:     " & source_file_txt.Value
    Debug.Print "source_file_txt.OldValue:  " & source_file_txt.OldValue

' Essentially, the above ONLY reflects the contents of the textbox
' when it has been changed by code -- it FAILS to reflect the contents of
' the textbox when it has been changed by the user!

    Debug.Print "(Len(Nz(source_file_txt, """")) > 0): " & (Len(Nz(source_file_txt, "")) > 0)
    Import_btn.Enabled = (Len(Nz(source_file_txt, "")) > 0)
    Debug.Print "Import_btn.Enabled:                   " & Import_btn.Enabled
End Sub
```

The following is a transcript from the Immediate window, with commentary inside braces {curly brackets} added after:

```
{Initially, nothing in the box ... response is good.} 
Form_Load() 5/21/2015 11:41:50 AM

enable_import() 5/21/2015 11:41:50 AM
source_file_txt:                 { Nothing is printed here and }
source_file_txt.Value:           { that truly reflects the     }
source_file_txt.OldValue:        { content of the box. Good.   }
(Len(Nz(source_file_txt, "")) > 0): False
import_btn.Enabled:                 False

{User pasted text into the box ... response is bad!}
source_file_txt_Change() 5/21/2015 11:42:02 AM

enable_import() 5/21/2015 11:42:02 AM
source_file_txt:                 { Nothing is printed here and }
source_file_txt.Value:           { that FAILS to reflect the   }
source_file_txt.OldValue:        { content of the box. Bad!    }
(Len(Nz(source_file_txt, "")) > 0): False
import_btn.Enabled:                 False

browse_btn_Click() 5/21/2015 11:42:16 AM

{VBA assigned text, returned from user's file browse, into the box ... response is good.}
enable_import() 5/21/2015 11:42:21 AM
source_file_txt:           C:\Users\mf\Documents\Assignments.xlsx
source_file_txt.Value:     C:\Users\mf\Documents\Assignments.xlsx
source_file_txt.OldValue:  C:\Users\mf\Documents\Assignments.xlsx
(Len(Nz(source_file_txt, "")) > 0): True { Above is good. }
import_btn.Enabled:                 True

{User cut text from the box ... response is bad!}
source_file_txt_Change() 5/21/2015 11:43:33 AM

enable_import() 5/21/2015 11:43:33 AM
source_file_txt:           C:\Users\mf\Documents\Assignments.xlsx
source_file_txt.Value:     C:\Users\mf\Documents\Assignments.xlsx
source_file_txt.OldValue:  C:\Users\mf\Documents\Assignments.xlsx
(Len(Nz(source_file_txt, "")) > 0): True { Above is bad! }
import_btn.Enabled:                 True
```

The bahavior is the same with or without object names prefixed by `Me.`.
How can I get the desired behavior?
I don't understand why `source_file_txt.Value` does not reflect what is really there.
Maybe it has something to do with Access trying to bind this form with the database -- it shows a meaningless (Record: 1 of 1 Search) navigation control at bottom.

---

**Solution**

I was using `source_file_txt.Value` when I should have used `source_file_txt.Text`.
The former doesn't change until it's too late, somehow.
Making that code change alone is not enough, however.
It causes a "focus" error in two situations. In those cases, I had to `SetFocus`.

Fixed code:

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
    source_file_txt.SetFocus
    enable_import
End Sub

Private Sub browse_btn_Click()
    source_file_txt = browsed_file()
    source_file_txt.SetFocus
    enable_import
End Sub

Private Sub enable_import()
    Import_btn.Enabled = (Len(Nz(source_file_txt.Text, "")) > 0)
End Sub
```

Comment: Would it be possible to narrow this down to "I expect this line to do this, but it is actually doing this"? :-)  Also my initial feeling is because you need to use `.Text` instead of `.Value` in one of those checks.  If that works a further explanation can be found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27528018/ in Hans answer.

Comment: @Newd - I've edited to pinpoint, both in the code and in the debug output, where/when program fails. I initially tried to also track `.Text` but got an error regarding focus. I'll see if i can pursue that line further...

Comment: OK, it seems that is the issue! Thanks for the link!

Comment: I just marked this as a duplicate...

Comment: I don't think I would consider it a duplicate, but don't forget to give HanUp an upvote on his post :-)

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
Import_btn.Enabled =Cbool(Len(Nz(source_file_txt,"")))
```

Comment: Thanks, but the problem is not in the enable logic itself, it is that the *value* of the textbox only reflects what the program puts there, not what the user puts/removes there.